# How to correct my program which has both terenary and bitwise operators?

Tags: c

```
/*to print bigger of two numbers using ternary operator*/
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{int a,b,c;
char p,q;
printf("enter the values of a,b,c:\n");
scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
a>b?((a>c)?printf("a is bigger"):printf("c is bigger")):((b>c)?printf("b is bigger"):printf("%d is bigger",c));
/*swap two characters using bitwise operator*/

printf("\n enter p and q:");
scanf("%c%c",&p,&q);
p=p^q;
q=p^q;
p=p^q;
printf("after swapping p =%c,q=%c",p,q);
}
```

this is the program  i typed . the first part of it i.e., bigger of three numbers came up with the right output but the second part i.e., swapping didnt take place.the output was somewhat like this 
enter p and q:ab
after swapping p=a,q= 
note: when i did the bitwise swapping program separately, i got the right output.
pls provide a solution to my problem and what can i do to

Comment: Don't use ternary here. Use `if` statements.

Comment: but in our exam.. it is mentioned that u have to use ternary.. kindly look into it

Comment: Did your instructor tell you to use `void main()`? It should be `int main(void)`. An `if` statement would definitely be better than a conditional (ternary) operator; I suppose the point is to teach how the conditional operator works, but there are better ways. Swapping using bitwise xor is ugly and unreliable (it fails if you swap an item with itself); using a temporary variable is simpler and clearer. I fear you're being taught bad habits.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a stupid exam question, with silly constraints on the code used, resulting in obfuscation and general uselessness to future users/visitors.

Comment: Did your instructor tell you to use the XOR swap?  Is s/he keeping a family member at gunpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem doesn't seem to be with your ternary or bitwise operators but with your inputs.

You should leave a space before `%c` when you read `p` and `q` -

```
scanf(" %c %c",&p,&q);
 /*    ^  ^ leave space     */
```

This is because `'\n'` from previous `scanf` remains in `stdin` which is read into `p` and character you input , goes in `q` , therefore after swapping you don't get desired output.

[See working code .](https://ideone.com/8wdh9b)

**Note**- `void main()` **->** `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc,char **argv)` .